# AVX equivalent for _mm_movelh_ps

Tags: c++, sse, intrinsics, avx

since there is no AVX version of `_mm_movelh_ps` I usually used `_mm256_shuffle_ps(a, b, 0x44)` for AVX registers as a replacement. However, I remember reading in other questions, that swizzle instructions without a control integer (like `_mm256_unpacklo_ps` or `_mm_movelh_ps`) should be preferred if possible (for some reason I don't know). Yesterday, it occurred to me, that another alternative might be using the following:

```cpp
_mm256_castpd_ps(_mm256_unpacklo_pd(_mm256_castps_pd(a), _mm256_castps_pd(b)));
```

Since the casts are supposed to be no-ops, is this better\equal\worse than using `_mm256_shuffle_ps` regarding performance?

Also, if it is truly the case, it would be nice if somebody could explain in simple words (I have very limited understanding of assembly and microarchitecture) why one should prefer instructions without a control integer.

Thanks in advance

**Additional note:**
Clang actually optimizes the shuffle to `vunpcklpd`: https://godbolt.org/z/9XFP8D
So it seems that my idea is not too bad. However, GCC and ICC create a shuffle instruction.

Comment: *[shuffles without immediate control byes] should be preferred if possible* Sounds like something I wrote :P

Comment: @PeterCordes: Thanks for your answer (below). I got the feeling that I should address my questions directly to you in the future. :D

Comment: Heh, I'll probably still only answer it if it has some hope of being useful to future readers.  BTW, note the update I made just after you accepted.

Comment: @PeterCordes Saw the update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Avoiding an immediate saves 1 byte of machine-code size; that's all.  It's at the bottom of the list for performance considerations, but all else equal shuffles like `_mm256_unpacklo_pd` with an implicit "control" are very slightly better than an immediate control byte for that reason.

(But taking the control operand in another vector like `vpermilps` can or `vpermd` requires is usually worse, unless you have some weird front-end bottleneck in a long-running loop, and can load the shuffle control outside the loop.  Not very plausible and at this point you'd have to be writing by hand in asm to be caring that much about code size/alignment; in C++ that's still not something you can really control directly.)

> Since the casts are supposed to be no-ops, is this better\equal\worse than using `_mm256_shuffle_ps` regarding performance?

**Ice Lake has 2/clock `vshufps` vs. 1/clock `vunpcklpd`**, according to testing by [uops.info](https://www.uops.info/table.html?search=vshufps&cb_lat=on&cb_tp=on&cb_uops=on&cb_ports=on&cb_SKL=on&cb_ICL=on&cb_measurements=on&cb_iaca30=on&cb_doc=on&cb_avx=on&cb_avx2=on) on real hardware, running on port 1 or port 5.  **Definitely use `_mm256_shuffle_ps`**.  The trivial extra code-size cost probably doesn't actually hurt at all on earlier CPUs, and is probably worth it for the future benefit on ICL, unless you're sure that port 5 won't be a bottleneck.

Ice Lake has a 2nd shuffle unit on port 1 that can handle some common XMM and in-lane YMM shuffles, including `vpshufb` and apparently some 2-input shuffles like `vshufps`.  I have no idea why it doesn't just decode `vunpcklpd` as a `vshufps` with that control vector, or otherwise manage to run that shuffle on port 1.  We know the shuffle HW itself can do the shuffle so I guess it's just a matter of control hardware to set up implicit shuffles, mapping an opcode to a shuffle control somehow.

Other than that, it's equal or better on older AVX CPUs; no CPUs have penalties for using PD shuffles between other PS instructions.  The only different on any existing CPUs is code-size.  Old CPUs like K8 and Core 2 had faster `pd` shuffles than `ps`, but no CPUs with AVX have shuffle units with that weakness.  Also, AVX non-destructive instructions level differences between which operand has to be the destination.

---

As you can see from the Godbolt link, there are zero extra instructions before/after the shuffle.  The "cast" intrinsics aren't doing conversion, just reinterpret to keep the C++ type system happy because Intel decided to have separate types for `__m256` vs. `__m256d` (vs. `__m256i`), instead of having one generic YMM type.  They chose not to have separate `uint8x16` vs. `uint32x4` vectors the way ARM did, though; for integer SIMD just `__m256i`.

So there's no need for compilers to emit extra instructions for casts, and in practice that's true; they don't introduce extra `vmovaps`/`apd` register copies or anything like that.

---

If you're using clang you can just write it conveniently and let clang's shuffle optimizer emit `vunpcklpd` for you.  Or in other cases, do whatever it's going to do anyway; sometimes it makes worse choices than the source, often it does a good job.

Clang gets this wrong with `-march=icelake-client`, still using `vunpcklpd` even if you write `_mm256_shuffle_ps`.  (Or depending on surrounding code, might optimize that shuffle into part of something else.)

[Related bug report](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=44113).

Comment: Interesting that Clang does this bad optimization even for `-march=icelake-client`. Do you think one should file a bug report to bring it to their attention?

Comment: Yeah, that should get reported.  That should get changed to preferring `vshufps` for icelake at least, probably also for generic.

Comment: Okay, I will take care of that (today or tomorrow) and post the link in the question.

Comment: A suggested-edit on this answer, or a comment, would be a better place for an LLVM bug-report link.  Thanks for taking the time to do that.  And BTW, you might want to link this answer, or at least the https://www.uops.info/table.html?search=vshufps&cb_lat=on&cb_tp=on&cb_uops=on&cb_ports=on&cb_SKL=on&cb_ICL=on&cb_measurements=on&cb_iaca30=on&cb_doc=on&cb_avx=on&cb_avx2=on uops.info search result, in your LLVM missed-optimization bug.

Comment: Okay, I 'll do as you suggested.

Comment: Okay, since self-registration is disabled, I have to wait for the admins to create an account for me until I can create the bug report. I 'll add the link as soon as I can.

Comment: N.B. On some very old processors ("Conroe") [`shufps`](https://www.uops.info/html-instr/SHUFPS_XMM_XMM_I8.html) used to be much slower than [`unpcklpd`](https://www.uops.info/html-instr/UNPCKLPD_XMM_XMM.html), and IceLake seems to be the first where `shufps` actually has better throughput -- maybe that was the motivation for clang to replace `shufps` by `unpcklpd` if possible. (Not disagreeing that this is a missed-optimization bug)

Comment: @chtz: I did mention that later in my answer; Core 2 and K8 having faster shuffles when you use 64-bit chunks.  Conroe/Merom is first-gen 65nm Core 2, that's what I meant; Penryn widened the shuffle ALU to 128-bit, up from 64, so `pshufb` and everything is fast, not just `pshuflw` or `shufpd`.  With more specific details in [Fastest way to do horizontal float vector sum on x86](//stackoverflow.com/q/6996764).  So yes, that's maybe relevant for `__m128i` without AVX. BTW, KNL has bad throughput for `vpshufb` and other byte/word element shuffles, but is fine with 32 and 64-bit chunks.

Comment: @PeterCordes Bug report is submitted. Link is added at the end of your answer, as suggested.